# Why if $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=b$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)=b$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, functions

Why is that if $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=b \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)=b?$$

This is often used to prove that the same properties that apply to sequences, also apply to functions, but I don't know from where this implication is coming from.

It is given that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=a$ and that is derived from the fact that $a \in D'f$. I am not sure about this part either, t.i., why the $a$ being a limit point implies that there is a sequence within the domain that converges to $a$.

Comment: What is $x_n$? What if $x_n=1$?

Comment: As said you must specify that $x_n\to b$, but also you should tell what level you're on. To some this is rather obvious and other would need a long explanation. For example do you know the definition of $\lim$? Can you show what definition you're using? Because it would follow quiet directly from the definition.

Comment: Please show the definition of $x_n$

Comment: Also note that the reverse implication isn't true, unless you mean that $\lim f(x_n)=b$ for **all** sequences $x_n\to b$.

Comment: I have updated my answer to address the question related to limit point.

Comment: @user You changed your problem after my answer without to say me about this. I think it's not fair.

Answer (score 2):

You should note that the proper result in question is like this:

> **Theorem**: Let $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =b$ and let $\{x_n\} $ be any sequence such that $x_n\neq a$ after a certain value of $n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=a$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) =b$.

The part $x_n\neq a$ is important and the result fails if this hypothesis is not met. One can prove the theorem using the definition of limit of sequences and functions.

If you are familiar with these definitions then you should try to prove the result. Otherwise it is best to understand it informally. If $x$ is near (but not equal to) $a$ then $f(x) $ is near $b$. And if $n$ grows without bound then $x_n$ is near $a$ (and by hypothesis not equal to $a$) and hence $f(x_n) $ is near $b$.

---

The second part of your question is related to the definition of a limit point and if you are familiar with it then you can prove the following result

> **Lemma**: If $a$ is a limit point of a non-empty set $A$ then there is a sequence $\{x_n\} $ such that $x_n\in A, x_n\neq a$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=a$.

The idea is to consider interval $(a-1/n,a+1/n)$ which necessarily contains some $x_n\in A$ with $x_n\neq a$.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = a$

Then if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = b$ we have that for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exist $\delta >0$ such that if $|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-b| < \varepsilon$

So, if we take a fixed $\varepsilon>0$, there exist a $\delta>0$ then by definition of limit, there exist $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n≥N$ then $|x_{n}-a|<\delta$ and that implies $|f(x_{n}) - b |<\varepsilon$

In other words, $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_{n}) = b$

Answer (score 0):

What the limit says is that however you approach the point $a$, the function $f(x)$ approaches $b$. Notice *however* you approach. That means in particular if you take any sequence $x_n$ which approaches $a$, then $f(x_n)$ must also approach $b$.

Formally if $f(x)\to b$ as $x\to a$, then by definition for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ so that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-b|<\varepsilon$. Now suppose $x_n$ is a sequence which converges to $a$. Then for any $\delta>0$ there is an $N$ so that $n\geq N$ implies $|x_n-a|<\delta$. But since for these $n\geq N$ we have $|x_n-a|<\delta$ we must also have $|f(x_n)-b|<\varepsilon$. This 'proves' $f(x_n)\to b$ as $n\to\infty$.

It is however very important that $x_n\to a$, you cannot take any sequence (obviously).

Comment: Ok, but why it follows from $a$ being a limit point within the domain of the function, that there exist such sequence $x_n$ that converges to $a$?